# Determining where in x-z plane, $f(z,t,x)$ is negative for all values of $0<t<\pi$

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to mark regions in $z - x$ plane in which, a know function,$f(x,z,t)$, is negative for all values of $0

How can I do that? I don't want to plot $f$ in $3D$. Could anyone help me?

The function f(t,x,z) is as below:

```
Re[0.125 (-21.2 + 
   Re[2 z Cos[2 t] - 
     2 z Cos[2 t]^2 + (2. E^(-I t) (E^(2 I t) (-8. - 3. x) z + 
          E^(12 I t) (-8. - 3. x) z + x z + E^(14 I t) x z + 
          E^(6 I t) (105.6 + 79.2 x - 8. z - 1. x z) + 
          E^(8 I t) (105.6 + 79.2 x - 8. z - 1. x z) + 
          E^(4 I t) (-79.2 x + 16. z + 3. x z) + 
          E^(10 I t) (-79.2 x + 16. z + 3. x z)) ((28.4 - 5. x + 
           0.25 x^2 + (-24.4 + 8. x - 0.125 x^2) Cos[
             2 t] + (-3. - 0.25 x) x Cos[4 t] + 
           0.125 x^2 Cos[6 t])^2)^(
        1/4))/(E^(2 I t) (-24. - 2. x) x + 
        E^(10 I t) (-24. - 2. x) x + x^2 + E^(12 I t) x^2 + 
        E^(4 I t) (-195.2 + 64. x - 1. x^2) + 
        E^(8 I t) (-195.2 + 64. x - 1. x^2) + 
        E^(6 I t) (454.4 - 80. x + 4. x^2))])]
```

Comment: Look up RegionPlot.

Comment: you should edit your post to fix the formatting..

Comment: reposted.. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/167282/2079

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I read your post as "for all values of t".  For `0<t<Pi`, you can use this approach and add the constraint to `Maximize` (untested).

brute force.. (warning this takes like a half hour)

```
(tab = Flatten[
    Table[ {x, y, Maximize[f[x, y, t], t][[1]]} , {x, -100, 100, 
      2}, {y, -100, 100, 2}], 1]) // AbsoluteTiming
Graphics[{Red, Point[Cases[tab, {x_, y_, t_ /; t <= 0} :> {x, y}]]}, 
 Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-100, 100}, {-100, 100}}]
```

[image]

there are a few convergence warnings thrown. I didn't investigate but those might be those isolated missing pixels..

here it is with the constraint: `Maximize[f[x, y, t], 0 < t <= Pi, t]`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assigning your expression to `expr` the region over some `z` and `x` domains can be viewed with [`RegionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html).

```
RegionPlot3D[expr < 0,
 {z, -100, 100}, {t, 0, π}, {x, -100, 100},
 AxesLabel -> Automatic
 ]
```

> [image]

Rotating this around shows that it the region is complex.

There are several options for viewing slices of the z-x plane. [`SliceContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceContourPlot3D.html) is a good one.  Combining it with [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Manipulate[
 SliceContourPlot3D[expr,
  {"YStackedPlanes", {tStar}},
  {z, -100, 100}, {t, 0, \[Pi]}, {x, -100, 100},
  Contours -> {0},
  ContourShading -> {LightGray, None},
  PlotPoints -> ControlActive[10, 50],
  AxesLabel -> Automatic
  ]
 ,
 {{tStar, 0}, 0, \[Pi]}
 ]
```

> [image]

There is also [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) with `Manipulate`.

```
Manipulate[
 ContourPlot[expr /. t -> tStar,
  {z, -100, 100}, {x, -100, 100},
  Contours -> {0},
  ContourShading -> {LightGray, None},
  PlotPoints -> ControlActive[5, 40]
  ]
 ,
 {{tStar, 0}, 0, \[Pi]}
 ]
```

> [image]

Hope this helps.

PS: You may need to refresh or click on the images to see the gifs animate.